# Showing a windows with XCB / Strange Behaviour

Tags: x11, xcb

I'm trying to show a window in xcb, inside the main window, but actually without luck.

The idea is that when the user press a button (in that case the X button) a small white window  is shown (just for test).

But actually i'm stuck on that step. I watched the example code here: 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X_Window_Programming/XCB

And tried to do the same in my application.

[**EDIT 28/10/2013**] **Now with that code i can show a window, but if i try to add other variable like int i=0, or whatever, the window doesn't appear, and no expose events were raised (all events that were raised are or 0 or 2 (even if i add the variables inside other events). Any idea?**

This is the XCB_KEY_PRESS event handler code: 
**Edit** (with the new code)

```
case XCB_KEY_PRESS:{
  xcb_key_press_event_t *kp = (xcb_key_press_event_t *)ev;
  if(kp->detail==53){
  printf("X pressed\n");
  uint32_t vals[2];
  mask = XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
  vals[0]=screen->white_pixel;
  vals[1]=XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS;
  win = xcb_generate_id(connection);
  xcb_create_window(
    connection,
    XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
    win,
    root,
    80,80,
    150,150,
    10,
    XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
    screen->root_visual,
    mask, values);

  mask = XCB_GC_FOREGROUND | XCB_GC_GRAPHICS_EXPOSURES;
  vals[0]=screen->white_pixel;
  vals[1]=0;
  background=xcb_generate_id(connection);
  xcb_create_gc(connection, background, win, mask, vals);
  xcb_map_window(connection,win);
  xcb_flush(connection);
  printf("finished\n");
  }
  printf("KEY_PRESS - Pressed: %d\n", kp->detail);
}
```

root is the root window obtained from xcb_screen_t variable.

The definition of background and win are the following:

```
xcb_window_t win;
xcb_gcontext_t background;
```

And i added even a XCB_EXPOSE event handler:

```
case XCB_EXPOSE:{
     printf("EXPOSE NEW WINDOW CREATED\n");
     xcb_poly_fill_rectangle(connection, win, background,1,&rectangle);
     xcb_flush(connection);
}
```

What is wrong with that code? What am i missing? (I'm trying to develop a very basic window manager, just for fun)

(My idea for that program is that when x is pressed an input box is shown, do you have any suggestion on how to do that?)

Comment: It looks like you forgot to call `xcb_create_window`.

Comment: The window was the root window obtained from xcb_screen_t, but i figured out the solution to the problem (probably).